# MapView in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I'm trying to get a `MapView` in a fragment but I don't know how. When I was researching this I saw some manipulation with the library, but it changes my extends `Fragment` in extends `FragmentActivity` and then everything gets messy!

Please help me with the code so I can have a `MapView` within a fragment.

Here's my code :

```
public class MyPlayerFrag extends Fragment{

    Context context;
    ImageView image;
    TextView caption;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout player_layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(com.idouchach.casa.tramway.R.layout.player, container, false);

        image = (ImageView) player_layout.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        caption = (TextView) player_layout.findViewById(R.id.caption);

        return player_layout;
    }

    public void updateImage(Content content){
        if(image != null){
            try{
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(content.getImg()));
                image.setImageBitmap(img);
                image.invalidate();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(caption != null)
            caption.setText(content.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no officially supported means of putting a `MapView` into a fragment, sorry.

Comment: Is there a no officially method to do it but not too dificult for a beginner ?

Comment: @SeïfaneIdouchach: Personally, I would not touch the workarounds that I have seen with a 10-meter pole.